# Web API Json Responce formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I've been searching in many places, but I didn't see this type of scenario

My web api response json is like (I have created a model for this) :

```
{
    "var1": 1,
    "test1": 2,
    "test2": 3
}
```

but I want my output response like the following :

```
{
    "type": "test",
    "query": "query used",
    "result": {
        "test1": 2,
        "test2": 3
    },
    "error": "if any error"
}
```

Do I need to create new model ? or any other easy way?
If I need to create new model, how will I assign existing model object values to new model?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ResponseDTO model and use it on the return of your Json.

```cs
public class ResponseDTO<T>
{
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public string Query {get;set;}
    public T Result {get;set;}
    public string Error {get;set;}
}
```

and on your controller, instead of returning your Model, you return an ResponseDTO, like this:

```cs
var response = new ResponseDTO<Model>();
response.Result = new Model(); //Do your things here
```

Doing it like this makes your response generic, so you can use with any kind of model

**UPDATE:**

For creating a new model without having to copy all properties, you can use and extension method like this:

```cs
public class Model()
{
    public int Var1 {get;set;}
    public string Test1 {get;set;}
    public string Test2 {get;set;}
}

public class NewModel(){
    public string Test1 {get;set;}
    public string Test2 {get;set;}
}
```

now you create an extension method, for example "ToNewModel", to convert the old model to the new design you want:

```cs
public NewModel ToNewModel(this Model model){
    var newModel = new NewModel()
    newModel.Test1 = model.Test1;
    newModel.Test2 = model.Test2;
}
```

and them, wherever you have your Model object, just call the extension method:

```cs
public JsonResult test()
{
    var model = new Model()

    //{  Fill your model properties  }

    var response = new ResponseDTO<NewModel>(); //Declare the response of the type of your new design
    response.Result = model.ToNewModel();
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, it really helps. One more thing i want is, I don't want to send all property values in my current model. i want to skip some properties and add some new into response.Result. like i skipped "var1" in my question

Comment: You need to create a new model if you want to conceal the properties, or just send them with null values. If the answer works for you, dont forget to mark it as answer please

Comment: How i will add old model matching property values to new model( my new model will have some new  properties added and some were removed compared to old model)..i can't go with looping as i have this type of model's so many.

Comment: You can create an Extension method to convert the properties you want. I'll update my answer with an example on how to do it

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: my model object can be list, so is there any way like directly object to object mapper, if any extra properties needed i can assign explicitly as you mentioned.

Comment: theres no way to do it automatically, you have to actually program the mapping